# PowerShell v2: Process with an Id of is not running

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to call a perl script using powershell as follows:

```
$plScript = Join-path $pwd 'Tools\myScript.pl'
$plOut = New-Item out.txt -type file -force
$plArgs = @($plScript, '--files','*.c', 'AddInc=\Tools','Addlib=\Tools')
Start-Process perl.exe -ArgumentList $plArgs -RedirectStandardOutput $plOut - wait
```

This fails with the following message:

```
Start-Process : Process with an Id of 80096 is not running.
+     Start-Process <<<<  perl.exe -ArgumentList  $plArgs  -RedirectStandardOutput $plOut -wait
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Using Trace-Command, I see where it fails, but can't understand what's wrong

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : System.ArgumentException: Process with an Id of 150588 is not running.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Int32 processId, String machineName)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand.start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand.BeginProcessing()
at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
```

What am I missing ?

Running this in powershell v3 succeeds with no errors... but I must support v2 for this assignment...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the perl process is exiting before the command can get the process's id.  Try it this way to see if you can get past this - perhaps figure out why perl is exiting early:

```
$p = Start-Process perl.exe -ArgumentList $plArgs -RedirectStandardOutput $plOut -PassThru
if (!$p.HasExited) {
    $p.WaitForExit()
} 
else {
    "Hmm why did the process exit so early, exit code was: $($p.ExitCode)"   
}
```

Comment: I tried this. The perl process ends successfully, with return code 0, but I still get the process id error. Really annoying... The script runs on a powerful server and takes less than 1 second to complete. How is that possible that it ends before ps has a chance to get pid ?

Comment: Isn't the pid available on `$p.Id`?  Also where are you getting the process id error?  If you are still getting that on Start-Process make sure you're not using the `-Wait` parameter.